# I have an error with Auth Service on Ionic 6

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, service

I have an error with Auth Service on Ionic 6, neither registration nor login works

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGwWe.jpg)

[Error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM7vD.jpg)

Comment: Hello Lucas and welcome to Stackoverflow, since you are new here please check this link on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, your question will get downvoted and closed if you do not change it. i would start by putting code instead of images and also share what you tried in order to debug your problem

Comment: You need to add authService register here to view it. You just added image of its usage , plus code should be text and not image.